# Convert UTC time into CString format

Tags: c++, mfc

I need to get the current system time in Unix UTC format and convert it into a CString. I am trying to do this like this

```
CTime time = CTime::GetCurrentTime();  
CString string = time.FormatGmt(L"%d");
```

code is running, but 'string' variable contains a wrong value, it should contain something like '1011173512', i.e. time in seconds since 1970. Does anyone has any clue why???

Comment: When you say "does not work", what do you mean by that? Do you get build errors? What errors do you get then? Do you get a runtime error (a crash)? Where is that, and what is the values of involved variables? Do you get unexpected results? Then for some specific input, what is you actual and expected output?

Comment: By saying "does not work" I mean that 'string' variable contains a wrong value (it should contain something like '1011173512')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `CTime::FormatGmt` uses the same formatting rules as `strftime`.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fe06s4ak.aspx

In particular, `%d` means "Day of month as decimal number (01 – 31)".

I suspect that you want a `time_t` or similar object. I suggest you want the `GetTime` method, which returns a `_time64_t`.

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s7y67z7.aspx

So:

```
CTime time = CTime::GetCurrentTime();  
CString string; string.Format(L"%lld", time.GetTime());
```

Comment: @IaroslavVivat If you think this answers your question in an acceptable way, you should mark it as such by clicking the checkmark next to the answer (read e.g. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) in the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help)).